# VLAN Flapping Betwen trunk port and access port

Tags: switching

`Jun  5 16:48:44.567 IST: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/2, changed state to up
Jun  5 16:48:45.725 IST: %SW_MATM-4-MACFLAP_NOTIF: Host 001c.c45b.9dd4 in vlan 102 is flapping between port Gi0/1 and port Fa0/2`

`interface FastEthernet0/2
 description "Connected to SI01TTS1-T1-2For Data "
 port-type nni
 switchport access vlan 102
 spanning-tree portfast
end
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description " connecting to SDC-SWH-IVRS-6 GI 0/2"
 port-type nni
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 102,200
 switchport mode trunk
end`

Comment: As i read it the host '001c.c45b.9dd4' is presenting on two ports within the 102 vlan - Fa0/2 and Gi0/1 causing the flap. The mac prefix '001CC4' is a Hewlett Packard device - Is this PC or server running any virtualisation software with multiple virtual machines(and associated MACs)? I notice you have portfast on Fa0/2 which is skipping certain steps of the spanning tree algorithm and assumes a single client patched in. May be worth temporarily removing this and monitor the log entries to see if spanning tree reports anything untoward. HTH,
3iron

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Unfortunately, it is not clear what you are asking. Please edit your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question. You have provided some configuration and example of a MAC flapping, but you did not actually ask any question.